# Error al Leer string con gets();

Tags: c++, string, entrada

Tengo problemas al leer un string en c++.

Como los string no tienen limite de caracteres (son dinamicos), pense leerlos con gets de la siguiente forma:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string Descripcion;

    cout<<"Ingrese la descripcion del Producto: ";
    gets(Descripcion);
    cout<<"La Descripcion del producto es: "<<Descripcion<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Pero code::blocks 16.01 me dice:

```
|10|error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char* gets(char*)'|
```

Hay una forma de leer un string sin ponerle limite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primero, tu error:

> char *gets( char * );

`gets( )` espera un puntero a cadena, y tu le estás pasando una `std::string`. El compilador no sabe como convertir la segunda en la primera, y se queja.

Otro error, **aún** mas grave:

Nada mas hacer

> man gets

Lo primero que nos encontramos en **una adventencia**

> **never use this function**

La función `gets( )` **no comprueba nada**; se limita a leer y almacenar. Es tan peligrosa que, desde C11, **ya no existe**. **NO LA USES**.

En C++, para leer líneas completas, puedes usar la función `getline( )`. Es el equivalente en C++ a lo que intentas hacer, pero con manejo adecuado de memoria, y usando `std::string`, como debe ser :-)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  string Descripcion;

  cout << "Ingrese la descripcion del Producto: ";
  getline( cin, Descripcion );
  cout << "La Descripcion del producto es: " << Descripcion << endl;

  return 0;
}
```