# 1 cadena la muestra incompleta y la segunda como si fuera la primera

Tags: c++

Este es mi código, el programa debe de leer 2 cadenas y decir cuál es más larga o decir si son iguales, pero solo me guarda la 2da cadena y a la hora de mostrarme en pantalla me la muestra incluso incompleta.
Me gustaría saber que falla y cómo solucionarlo?
Es puro código C++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char str1 [] = "";
    char str2 [] = "";
    
    gets(str1);
    gets(str2);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    int long_str1 = strlen(str1);
    int long_str2 = strlen(str2);
    
    cout<<"\n\n";
    if(strcmp(str1 , str2) == 0){
        cout<<"Son iguales"<<endl;
    }else if(long_str1 > long_str2){
        cout<<"La cadena "<<str1<<" es mas larga que "<<str2<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"La cadena "<<str2<<" es mas larga que "<<str1<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La longitud la cadena la conviertes a entero y operas con su longitud. Lo que yo haría sería compararlos directamente, no mediante una variable numérica.

Pero de todos modos, yendo a tu código, para definir la cadena `str1` usas `char str1[] = ""`; no está bien, ya que primero no se pueden declarar arreglos abiertos y segundo aunque se declarara como arreglo con un tope tampoco es necesario pues C++ tiene el tipo `string`

Deberías declarar a las variables `str` y `str2` como `string`. Esto te permite liberar a la cadena de un tope.

```
string str
```

Pero recordar que se deben leer las cadenas con `getline`. En el código se lee de la siguiente manera

```
getline(cin, str1);
```

Para leer su longitud se usa el indicador `.c_str());`

```
int long_str2 = strlen(str2.c_str());
```

Y para comparar también se usa el mismo indicador

Adicionalmente faltó declarar la libería `iostream`

El código queda así:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str1;
    string str2;
    
    getline(cin, str1);
    getline(cin, str2);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    int long_str1 = strlen(str1.c_str());
    int long_str2 = strlen(str2.c_str());
    
    cout<<"\n\n";
    if(strcmp(str1.c_str() , str2.c_str()) == 0){
        cout<<"Son iguales"<<endl;
        
    }else if(long_str1 > long_str2){
        cout<<"La cadena "<<str1<<" es mas larga que "<<str2<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"La cadena "<<str2<<" es mas larga que "<<str1<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Referencias:**
[Error al Leer string con gets();](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109646/error-al-leer-string-con-gets)
https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/c%2B%2B/como-obtener-la-longitud-de-una-cadena-usando-la-funcion-strlen/1042789026/